# How to add timestamp data to PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add some data to a PostgreSQL table using `INSERT TO` on pgAdmin4.

This is the code that I am trying to run;

```
INSERT INTO raw(id,object_id, confidence, timestamp)
VALUES  (1,9.0,0.012145853244069600,2020-05-20 13:02:52.281964)
```

And I am getting the following response;

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "13"`

I am quite new to SQL and PostgreSQL, so go easy on me. I assume that it is something wrong with handling time related data.

Answer (score 2):

[Use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO raw(id,object_id, confidence, timestamp)
VALUES  (1,9.0,0.012145853244069600,'2020-05-20 13:02:52.281964')
```